# Can foreigner travel domestically with expired visa?

Tags: visas, air-travel, domestic-travel

Iam a foreigner, with a tourist visa expired on December 2018.

I applied for tourist visa extension and my case is still pending.

Can I travel domestically the US with my expired visa?

Comment: Did your *visa* expire in December 2018 or your I-94?  When does or did the other one expire?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but be aware that **airline passenger manifests are transmitted to various law enforcement agencies**.

Meaning, if ICE or another agency is specifically looking for you, they'll know where to find you.

Provided your foreign Passport is still valid, you can use that at the terminal entrance.  TSA does not check Visas during the screening process.

If you're driving or taking a bus or train, ID is rarely required.  At least I've never been asked for ID on Amtrak.

Comment: Since the case is still pending, it's unlikely that ICE is looking for her, and anyway they probably know where to find her because she will have given her address in applying for the extension.  Do you have any links to support the assertion that domestic manifests are sent to law enforcement agencies?  I am curious to know more about that.  I can attest from personal experience to the fact that TSA agents do not check visas (or otherwise consider immigration status) but Border Patrol sometimes monitors TSA checkpoints, as far as I know only near the border with Mexico.